# Internet Explorer 10 ignoring css <a> font color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Currently I'm having an issue with Internet Explorer 10.  I'm pretty sure this happens in older version as well, but 10 is currently the oldest version I have access to test this on.

I'm trying to simply set a CSS font color for an  tag within a div class.

```
.dropdown-content a {
    color: #292929;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #B40101;
}
```

When I load the page up in internet explorer, it seems to have completely ignored the 'color' part of the CSS when I try to look at the CSS in the dev console.

Here's a [Screenshot of the CSS in the IE development console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K8Yy.png)
As you can see, it doesn't even display the color style code even though I obviously put it in the CSS file.

I've tried all the solutions I could find but nothing seems to allow me to get the browser to even recognize the existence of the color css style...

Anyone have any idea why IE is doing this?  It's driving me crazy!

Comment: try adding !important ? perhaps something over-writing it. Try editing the css directly in the console/element inspector, try adding an inline style, all just to see if anything works

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to my own question.  This actually wasn't a CSS issue.  At the top of my html page I had the following:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Simply removing this line fixed the CSS issues I was experiencing immediately.